# Google App Script Debug only for proprietary

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want that only proprietary of spreadsheet can debug google app script of Spreadsheet. therefore avoid that editors can debug the code.

I really need that. How can i get it?

---

FINAL ANSWER:

The only way is coding ADDONS 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/

Comment: The only way is to use an Add-on.

Comment: thanks @SandyGood !

Comment: Please consider put a star on this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36763190

Comment: I just Star it .  I think that is good idea can edit and/or debug Google App Script Debug only for proprietary of spreadsheet for example. it is mean, that user with editors rights can use a custom menu but can not view o edit the code of bound scripts or change Libraries into Script Editor ... Resume, like say @SandyGood today the only way is by ADD-ON

Comment: @SandyGood Is possible that ADDON only work for users with editor rights?

Comment: Yes.  You can get the current user, and then check if they are an editor of the file.

Comment: ok @SandyGood. Thanks!. Also i note that when editors users work with sheets Protected (only propietary can edit) the MENU ADDON turn disabled . It is a pity